# Increasing the maximum DNS record size on a Cisco 800 Router

Tags: domain-name-system, cisco, cache

Is it possible to increase the maximum record size/cache size supported by the DNS server embedded in a Cisco 800 series router (886VA in my case)? I cannot query large (1500b) TXT records without bypassing Cisco's `ip dns server`.

Comment: Why the heck are your TXT records this large?

Comment: Some embedded systems have limited methods of configuration (or set modes in this case) and sometimes you end up with horrible kludges to make things work "just right".

Comment: For dns responses larger than 512bytes you (often) need tcp/53. Is that port allowed in your ACL?

Comment: @Zabuzzman yup TCP 53 is enabled, and according to a network TAP installed it is actively used as well. The limit appears to be 1300b records and above.

Comment: Stupid question -why do you not just use a real dns server? I have all kinds of routers in my networks but I never use the router as dns SERVER.

Answer (score 1):

Call Cisco and mention to them that it's 2014, and perhaps they should support EDNS0, which has only been around for 10 years now.